# How do you convert a 16 bit unsigned integer to a larger 8 bit unsigned integer?

Tags: c++

I have a function that needs to return a 16 bit unsigned int vector, but for another from which I also call this one, I need the output in 8 bit unsigned int vector format. For example, if  I start out with:

```
std::vector<uint16_t> myVec(640*480);
```

How might I convert it to the format of:

```
std::vector<uint8_t> myVec2(640*480*4);
```

UPDATE (more information):
I am working with libfreenect and its getDepth() method. I have modified it to output a 16 bit unsigned integer vector so that I can retrieve the depth data in millimeters. However, I would also like to display the depth data. I am working with some example code c++ from the freenect installation, which uses glut and requires an 8 bit unsigned int vector to display the depth, however, i need the 16 bit to retrieve the depth in millimeters and log it to a text file. Therefore, i was looking to retrieve the data as a 16 bit unsigned int vector in glut's draw function, and then convert it so that I can display it with the glut function that's already written.

Comment: Need more information. How do the 8-bit values relate to the 16-bit values?

Comment: Without copying data (i.e. you want to re-assign ownership and re-interpret the type of the underlying buffer) this is very hard as `std::vector` does not expose any way to externally overwrite its internal buffer pointer.

Comment: what you want to do is more complex than just converting 16-bit numbers to 8-bit numbers, see my answer for more info

Comment: So you have the same number of values in *both* vectors right? How do you convert a single value from 16-bit to 8-bit? Do they need to be scaled in some way? Does the maximum 16-bit value need to map onto the maximum 8-bit value (for example)?

Comment: @Galik he does, that's what I was getting at in my answer. He needs some sort of Brightness Transfer Function to map his data set into values that mean something in an image.

Comment: @RyanP I think you are probably right and your answer is very informative but he needs to put this in the question so we don't have to guess.

Comment: This is really confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per your update, assuming the 8-bit unsigned int is going to be displayed as a gray scale image, what you need is akin to a Brightness Transfer Function. Basically, your output function is looking to map the data to the values 0-255, but you don't necessarily want those to correspond directly to millimeters. What if all of your data was from 0-3mm? Then your image would look almost completely black. What if it was all 300-400mm? Then it'd be completely white because it was clipped to 255.

A rudimentary way to do it would be to find the minimum and maximum values, and do this:

```
double scale = 255.0 / (double)(maxVal - minVal);
for( int i = 0; i < std::min(myVec.size(), myVec2.size()); ++i )
{
    myVec2.at(i) = (unsigned int)((double)(myVec.at(i)-minVal) * scale);
}
```

depending on the distribution of your data, you might need to do something a little more complex to get the most out of your dynamic range.

Edit: This assumes your glut function is creating an image, if it is using the 8-bit value as an input to a graph then you can disregard.

Edit2: An update after your other update. If you want to fill a 640x480x4 vector, you are clearly doing an image. You need to do what I outlined above, but also the 4 dimensions that it is looking for are Red, Green, Blue, and Alpha. The Alpha channel needs to be 255 at all times (this controls how transparent it is, you don't want it to be transparent), as for the other 3... that value you got from the function above (the scaled value) if you set all 3 channels (channels being red, green, and blue) to the same value it will appear as grayscale. For example, if my data ranged from 0-25mm, for a pixel who's value is 10mm, I would set the data to 255/(25-0)* 10 = 102 and therefore the pixel would be (102, 102, 102, 255)

Edit 3: Adding wikipedia link about Brightness Transfer Functions - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_mapping

Answer (score 3):

> How might I convert it to the format of:
>
> std::vector myVec2; such that myVec2.size() will be twice as
>   big as myVec.size()?

```
myVec2.reserve(myVec.size() * 2);
for (auto it = begin(myVec); it!=end(myVec); ++it)
{
    uint8_t val = static_cast<uint8_t>(*it); // isolate the low 8 bits
    myVec2.push_back(val);
    val = static_cast<uint8_t>((*it) >> 8); // isolate the upper 8 bits
    myVec2.push_back(val);
}
```

Or you can change the order of `push_back()`'s if it matters which byte come first (the upper or the lower).

Answer (score -1):

Straightforward way:

```
std::vector<std::uint8_t> myVec2(myVec.size() * 2);
std::memcpy(myVec2.data(), myVec.data(), myVec.size());
```

or with the use of the standard library

```
std::copy( begin(myVec), end(myVec), begin(myVec2));
```

Comment: Would the result of this depend on endian-ness of the machine?

Comment: @triple_r yes it would, but it's not clear how the op intends to interpret the data... if he undid the operation on a machine with the same endian-ness, it wouldn't matter.

Comment: @triple_r It would but, as RyanP says, it isn't really specified. `std::copy` shouldn't have this problem, I think.

Comment: Yep, you are correct. I was just curious about what will happen with `memcpy`.